# How to implement a light weight database based FIFO queue in java

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, thread-safety, queue

We have an Servlet based application which can uploads files.
Uploaded files are saved in the server , and after that it is delegated for File Processing and later insert in our Mongo DB.

Files are large greater than 50 mbs and it will take 30m -1 hour depending upon server load.
Problem happens when multiple files gets processed at a time in separate threads off course, but it will eventually slow up the system and finally one of the thread gets aborted , which we can never trace it.

So we are now planning for a Multiple Producer - single consumer based approach , where file jobs are queued one by one , and the Consumer will consume it from queue one by one , but sequentially .

Provided we need the clustering capability to implemented in the application later on ,
For this approach we are planning to implement the below process.

1. when a file job comes, we will put it in a mongo collection with status New.
2. Next it will call the consumer thread immediately .
3. Consumer will check if there is already a running tasks with status "Running"
4. if there is no running status , it will start the task .
5. Upon completion ,before ending, consumer will again check the table, if there are any tasks with status NEW , if it is there ,it will take the task IN FIFO manner by checking the time stamp , and the process continuous.
6. If there is current Running tasks, it will simply insert the new task to db. since there is a already running consumer ,that thread will take care of the new job inserted into db ,while the current process ends.

By this way , we can also ensure that it will run smoothly on the clustered environment also without any additional configuration .

There are message queue based solution with RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ , but wee neeeds to minimize the additional component configuration

Let me know if our approach is correct or ,do we have a better solution out there .

Thanks,

Comment: [Capped Collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/)

Comment: You can [embed ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html) into your VM.